# How to indent content in properties file in java

Tags: java, indentation, properties-file

I want to indent content in my properties file.

For example:

```
              This is center aligned title
This is my first line
This is my second line
```

I could manage seperating the lines from each other using `'\n'`, however, I don't understand how to center align my first line.

The `'\t'` parameter also does not seem to help.

Comment: Center aligned in properties file. I cannot imagine the requirement. Can elaborate more on why you wan to do this. Just to add How a file is read is dependent on editor and files don't have width limit as such.

Comment: just add it as a comment #      Centered section title

Comment: @Funtik Could you please elaborate more on that one?!

Comment: Property files are basically for storing key value pairs with some comments and nothing more. You shouldn't store art in it!

Comment: @bobbel anything is good to create art with, the question is if you should create art while coding :P

Comment: @owlstead yes!!! It's  what we do everyday

Answer (score 1):

So just try the following pattern:

```
#               This will be centered
property1=Value1
property2=Value2
property3=Value3
property4=Value4
```